# Proof $\sqrt[3]{a-b} + \sqrt[3]{b-c} + \sqrt[3]{c-a} \neq 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $a,b,c \in R$, and they are not equal.

> Proof $\sqrt[3]{a-b} + \sqrt[3]{b-c} + \sqrt[3]{c-a} \neq 0$

I can prove this statement by contradiction ($\sqrt[3]{a-b} + \sqrt[3]{b-c} + \sqrt[3]{c-a} = 0 \Rightarrow \sqrt[3]{a-b} + \sqrt[3]{b-c} = - \sqrt[3]{c-a} \Rightarrow 3(\sqrt[3]{(a-b)^{2}(b-c)} + \sqrt[3]{(a-b)(b-c)^{2}})=0 \Rightarrow \dots)$

But I want a solution with Euler's formula ($x^{3}+y^{3}+z^{3}-3xyz = (x+y+z)(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}-xy-xz-yz)$). If we set $x=\sqrt[3]{a-b}, y=\sqrt[3]{b-c}, z= \sqrt[3]{c-a}$, then 
$$0-3\sqrt[3]{(a-b)(b-c)(a-c)} = (\sqrt[3]{a-b} + \sqrt[3]{b-c} + \sqrt[3]{c-a})(A)$$

Since $3\sqrt[3]{(a-b)(b-c)(a-c)}\neq 0$, if I show $A\neq 0$, the proof is complete, but I can't proov it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The constraint for $a$, $b$ and $c$ being not all equal are not strong enough.

\begin{align}
  x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz &= (x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx) \\
  &= (x+y+z) \times \frac{(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2}{2} \\
  x &= \sqrt[3]{a-b} \\
  y &= \sqrt[3]{b-c} \\
  z &= \sqrt[3]{c-a} \\
  x^3+y^3+z^3 &= 0 \\
\end{align}

Note that

- $xyz = 0 \implies a=b \lor b=c \lor c=a$
- $x=y=z \implies a=b=c$

> Distinct $a,b,c$ guarantee
>   $$xyz \ne 0$$ and $$\frac{(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2}{2} \ne 0$$

Answer (score 2):

Say there exist $a,b,c$ not equal such that

$$\sqrt[3]{a-b} + \sqrt[3]{b-c} + \sqrt[3]{c-a} = 0$$

Then we have

$$\sqrt[3]{a-b} + \sqrt[3]{b-c} = \sqrt[3]{a-c}$$

Write $x= \sqrt[3]{a-b}$ and $y= \sqrt[3]{b-c}$, then we have $$(x+y)^3 = x^3+y^3$$

So $3xy(x+y)=0$ which means that $a=b$ or $b= c$ or $c=a$. A contradiction.

Comment: the problem is here that you write $$\sqrt[3]{c-a}=-\sqrt[3]{a-c}$$

Comment: how do you define $$\sqrt[3]{x}$$?

Comment: ok Christian, thats all i want to say....

Comment: @ChristianF As I mentioned, I don't want to use contradiction!

Comment: " I don't want to use contradiction"  Then don't.  If $a\ne b; b\ne c; c\ne a$ then $3xy(x+y) \ne 0$ and $(x+y)^3 \ne x^3 +y^3$ and $\sqrt[3]{a-b}+ \sqrt[3]{b-c} + \sqrt[3]{a-c} \ne 0$.  No, contradiction assumed or shown.

Answer (score 0):

i would substitute $$x=\sqrt[3]{a-b},y=\sqrt[3]{b-c},z=\sqrt[3]{c-a}$$
then we get $$x^3+y^3+z^3=...$$?

Comment: $x^{3} = a-b$ ...... $y^{3} = b-c$ ...... $z^{3} = c-a$ ...... $\Rightarrow x^{3} + y^{3} + z^{3} = 0$